# Empty lines between sections/div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a responsive static web page using the below HTML and styles. I see there are blank lines between the borders (horizondal) (I am not sure it's from Div or Section) I would like to remove those blank lines, I tried to add margin: 0px and padding: 0px for almost all the elements I used in this styles nothing is working for me.
Someone, please help me what I'm doing wrong and where I need to make this change in order to remove those white lines

The highlighted area's lines need to be removed or reduced to look more closer to each sections/divs.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS2bM.png)
`

```css
.main_box {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52));
  color: black;
  width: 1150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.25), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.3);
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #313133;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 24px rgba(79, 209, 197, .64);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 1000px;
  min-width: calc(300px + 12px);
  min-height: calc(50px + 12px);
  border: 6px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 255, 203, .64);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  color: #313133;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

button:hover::before,
button:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #00FFCB;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: ring 1.5s infinite;
}

button:hover::after,
button:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#disp_result {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.52), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52));
  color: #03202C;
  width: 650px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(20, 30, 40, 50.25), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 205, 255, 0.3);
}


/* Div Rows*/

.container {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  width: 420px;
  float: right;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 10px height: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}

right:hover::after,
right:focus::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.right:hover,
.right:focus {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

right:hover::before,
right:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

right:hover::after,
right:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:not(:disabled)~label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  left: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(215, 5%, 10%);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  color: hsla(215, 5%, 10%, 1);
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h5 {
  color: #999;
}

p {
  font-weight: 60;
  top: -30px;
  left: -10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)~label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: 150, 75%, 45%;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border: 5px solid hsl(150, 75%, 45%);
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}

section>div {
  padding: 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
  <section>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" value="cb1" style="opacity:0">
      <label for="cb1" class="main">
                    <h2>New York</h2>
                    <p>New York City comprises 5 boroughs sitting where the Hudson River meets the Atlantic Ocean. At its core is Manhattan, a densely populated borough that’s among the world’s major commercial, financial and cultural centers</p>
                </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" value="cb2" style="opacity:0">
      <label for="cb2" class="main">
                    <h2>Washinton DC</h2>
                    <p>Washington, DC, the U.S. capital, is a compact city on the Potomac River, bordering the states of Maryland and Virginia. It’s defined by imposing neoclassical monuments and buildings</p>
                </label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" value="cb3" style="opacity:0">
      <label for="cb3">
                        <h2>Chicago</h2>
                        <p>Chicago, on Lake Michigan in Illinois, is among the largest cities in the U.S. Famed for its bold architecture, it has a skyline punctuated by skyscrapers such as the iconic John Hancock Center</p>
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="cb4" value="cb4" style="opacity:0">
      <label for="cb4">
                        <h2>Los Angeles</h2>
                        <p>Los Angeles is a sprawling Southern California city and the center of the nation’s film and television industry. Near its iconic Hollywood sign, studios such as Paramount Pictures, Universal and Warner Brothers offer behind-the-scenes tours</p>
                    </label>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: There are hidden checkboxes (opacity 0) at the top of the divs that are taking up extra space.

Answer (score 1):

How's this - I would make the container flex then move the border and padding to the right div and remove the float:

```css
.main_box {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52));
  color: black;
  width: 1150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.25), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.3);
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #313133;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 24px rgba(79, 209, 197, .64);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 1000px;
  min-width: calc(300px + 12px);
  min-height: calc(50px + 12px);
  border: 6px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 255, 203, .64);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  color: #313133;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

button:hover::before,
button:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #00FFCB;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: ring 1.5s infinite;
}

button:hover::after,
button:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#disp_result {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.52), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52));
  color: #03202C;
  width: 650px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(20, 30, 40, 50.25), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 205, 255, 0.3);
}


/* Div Rows*/

.container {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  width: 420px;
  text-align: justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

right:hover::after,
right:focus::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.right:hover,
.right:focus {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

right:hover::before,
right:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

right:hover::after,
right:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:not(:disabled)~label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(215, 5%, 10%);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  color: hsla(215, 5%, 10%, 1);
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h5 {
  color: #999;
}

p {
  font-weight: 60;
  top: -30px;
  left: -10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)~label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: 150, 75%, 45%;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border: 5px solid hsl(150, 75%, 45%);
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}

section>div {
  padding: 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" value="cb1" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;">
      <label for="cb1" class="main">
                    <h2>New York</h2>
                    <p>New York City comprises 5 boroughs sitting where the Hudson River meets the Atlantic Ocean. At its core is Manhattan, a densely populated borough that’s among the world’s major commercial, financial and cultural centers</p>
                </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" value="cb2" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;">
      <label for="cb2" class="main">
                    <h2>Washinton DC</h2>
                    <p>Washington, DC, the U.S. capital, is a compact city on the Potomac River, bordering the states of Maryland and Virginia. It’s defined by imposing neoclassical monuments and buildings</p>
                </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" value="cb3" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;">
      <label for="cb3">
                        <h2>Chicago</h2>
                        <p>Chicago, on Lake Michigan in Illinois, is among the largest cities in the U.S. Famed for its bold architecture, it has a skyline punctuated by skyscrapers such as the iconic John Hancock Center</p>
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="cb4" value="cb4" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;">
      <label for="cb4">
                        <h2>Los Angeles</h2>
                        <p>Los Angeles is a sprawling Southern California city and the center of the nation’s film and television industry. Near its iconic Hollywood sign, studios such as Paramount Pictures, Universal and Warner Brothers offer behind-the-scenes tours</p>
                    </label>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code. And there were problems you can see the modified code from [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiihd/su0Lhnjk/36/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" value="cb2" style="display: none">
```

you can use full code in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiihd/su0Lhnjk/36/)

```
.main_box {
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255,0.52), rgba(255,255,255,0.52));
color: black;
/* width: 1150px; */
padding: 10px;
margin: 5em auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 35px;
box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.25), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(55, 55, 55, 
  0.3);
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try *adding*

```
input[type="checkbox"] { margin-top: -10px; }
```

Not sure how it will work responsively though.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying ".right" and "label" fixes the spacing problem.

1. Move the border from "label" to ".right".
2. Add padding to ".right".
3. Reduce the width of ".right" to compensate for the added padding and border.

```css
.right {
    width: 392px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 10px height: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
}

label {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}
```